# What should I use instead of NARQ?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, close-reasons

Some questions just aren't questions, usually meant to be an answer on a question or similar, but there's no NARQ close reason any more.

What should I vote to close such questions as?

<sup>This is the question that prompted me to ask this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144450/transparent-backed-ios7-status-bar-enjoy</sup>

Comment: Surely Unclear what you are asking as you can;t work out what the question is

Comment: @Mark This is what I used for the linked question but I wondered if there was a better alternative? Some sites have an off-topic reason for it.

Comment: For lack of NARQ and no doubt this there are long threads on meta stack overflow

Comment: @Mark Yes, but none seemed applicable to this site, which is very different to SO.

Comment: Rather than asking what close reason corresponds to NARQ, I'd suggest you ask whether the post needs to be closed according to one of the current close reasons; if yes, use that one. If no, don't vote to close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had "Not a real question" as a close reason in the past, but some people might see it as offensive (because usually the OP did think it was a question). Voting to close such posts as "Unclear what you are asking" seems a reasonable alternative (and already hints at the fact that the question needs to be improved).

Comment: Yes, I thought that any similar text to the old NARQ in a custom close reason would suffer from the same problem that NARQ did originally.

Comment: Which  was one reason for SO removing NARQ as well